# With opencsv need to clear my file before writing

Tags: java, csv, opencsv

My problem is that I full a csv file but I want every time that Ii run my code to empty the csv and then write tha new data.

This method is called from my main body in a FOR loop every time I run the code...

```
public static void csv_output() throws Exception {
  FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("output/out.csv", true);
  //true refers to append
  PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw, false);
  //pw.flush();
  //clears the Buffer
  if (Auctionhouse.current_epoch == 1) {
    pw.print("Epoch");
    pw.print(",");
    for (int j = 0; j < Run_process.total_Agents; j++) {
      pw.print(Chromosome.chromosome.get(j).ID + "_Balance");
      pw.print(",");
    }
    for (int k = 0; k < Stockhouse.total_stocks; k++) {
      pw.print(Stockhouse.stockP.get(k).stock_Id);
      pw.print(",");
    }
  }
  pw.println();
  pw.print(Auctionhouse.current_epoch);
  pw.print(",");
  for (int i = 0; i < Run_process.total_Agents; i++) {
    String ag = Portfolio.Agent_balance.get(i) + "";
    pw.print(ag);
    pw.print(",");
  }
  for (int j = 0; j < Stockhouse.total_stocks; j++) {
    String pr = Auctionhouse.total_prices.get(Auctionhouse.current_epoch - 1).get(j) + "";
    pw.print(pr);
    pw.print(",");
  }
}
pw.flush();
pw.close();
fw.close();
```

Flush doesn't work.

P.S: I want to append so that I can write the data in every loop.

Comment: Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks. The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow.  As an aside, the text of your question is confusing because it is contradictory.  At the top you say you want to clear the file, yet at the bottom you say you want to append info.

Comment: what u mean by flush not working ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to clear "output/out.csv", you can simply change the argument of `FileWriter` to `false`.

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("output/out.csv", false);
```

As said in the documenation of the [FileWriter constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter%28java.io.File,%20boolean%29) the second argument specify if you want to append or not. in your case, if you want to clear the data you can simply pass `false` and it will write at the beginning of the file. You should execute this code when your application is starting.

**EDIT:** 
To clear the content of the file without deleting it. If you implement this code, you will need to catch `IOexception` and maybe create a function to execute the code but this should do it.

```
   public static void clearCsv() throws Exception {
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("output/out.csv", false); 
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw, false);
        pw.flush();
        pw.close();
        fw.close();
    }
```

Comment: each time i run the code i have a loop where this function called.So in order to write new data in every loop i need to append data.After when i want to run the project again i need to insert new data at the same file so there i need the file to be clear!

Comment: @user2102151 See the answer of stolzem. You can delete the file at the start of your application, or determine in your fonction if you need to append or not. But IMHO, I would delete the file before beginning to append.

Comment: the problem is that i need to clear somehow and not delete it!Also i need to append in every loop,but to clear every time i want to run the project.E.g now i clear my excel (csv) file before i run my project...

Comment: @user2102151 Do you need the file to exist or not? Cause if you don't need it, you can delete it and `FileWriter` will create it for you. But if need the file and just want to clear it, I will edit my question with some code.

Comment: See my edit to clear the content. If you have more question, just ask for some more explanation.

Comment: with your new code no data is written to my file,remains empty!

Comment: @user2102151 The new code is to be executed when your application start not in `csv_output()`.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand you want to have an empty "output/out.csv" file before you enter your for loop. So just remove the file at program start - if it exists.

```
File outFile = new File("output/out.csv");

// delete out file if it exists
if (outFile.exists()) {
    System.out.println("Old out.csv file exists. Removing...);
    outFile.delete();
}
```